# Editable QTableView of complex SQL query

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel, qsqlquerymodel

**How can I make an editable QTableView displaying data from a complex SQLite query?**

I need to fill a QTableView with data from several SQLite tables. This needs to be editable by the user.

As the queries are a bit complex (including JOINs and CASE WHEN etc.), I'm doing this via a QSqlTableModel and a QSqlQuery. I have been told, however, that this is not how QSqlTableModels should be used. So, can someone please show me how to get a result like the one shown here via the proper way?

Also, while my QTableViews are editable, the results don't seem to get stored in the SQLite database. (When I comment out fill_tables, I still get the original results after restarting the GUI. Changing the EditStrategy to OnFieldChange doesn't help.) Is that because I'm handling QSqlTableModel wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtSql import (QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, 
                         QSqlRelationalTableModel, QSqlRelation)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
from PyQt5.Qt import QSortFilterProxyModel
import sys

db_file = "test.db"

def create_connection(db_file):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(db_file)
    if not db.open():
        print("Cannot establish a database connection to {}!".format(db_file))
        return False
    return db


def fill_tables():
    q = QSqlQuery()
    q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Manufacturers;")
    q.exec_("CREATE TABLE Manufacturers (Company TEXT, Country TEXT);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Manufacturers VALUES ('VW', 'Germany');")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Manufacturers VALUES ('Honda' , 'Japan');")

    q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;")
    q.exec_("CREATE TABLE Cars (Company TEXT, Model TEXT, Year INT);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('Honda', 'Civic', 2009);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('VW', 'Golf', 2013);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('VW', 'Polo', 1999);")


class CarTable(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_UI()
        self.create_model()

    def create_model(self):
        query = """
        SELECT (comp.company || " " || cars.model) as Car,
                comp.Country,
                (CASE WHEN cars.Year > 2000 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) as this_century
        from manufacturers comp left join cars
            on comp.company = cars.company
        """
        raw_model = QSqlTableModel()
        q = QSqlQuery()
        q.exec_(query)
        self.check_error(q)
        raw_model.setQuery(q)

        self.model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.model.setSourceModel(raw_model)
        self.setModel(self.model)

        # filtering:
        self.model.setFilterKeyColumn(0)
        self.model.setFilterFixedString('VW')

    def init_UI(self):
        self.resize(500,300)

    def check_error(self, q):
        lasterr = q.lastError()
        if lasterr.isValid():
            print(lasterr.text())
            exit(1)


def main():
    mydb = create_connection(db_file)
    if not mydb:
        sys.exit(-1)
    fill_tables()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = CarTable()
    ex.show()
    result = app.exec_()

    if (mydb.open()):
        mydb.close()

    sys.exit(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried using a QSqlRelationalTableModel instead, but I can't get the same complexity of queries done, and it also doesn't save the changes, just like the code above. This is as far as I got on that attempt:

```
     def create_model_alternative(self):
        self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel()
        self.model.setTable("Cars")
        self.model.setRelation(0, QSqlRelation("Manufacturers", "Company",
                                               "Company, Country"))  
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.select()

        # filtering:
        self.model.setFilter("cars.Company = 'VW'")
```

---

To answer incoming questions:

**Editability:**

In this example, the only column that is definitely *required* to be editable (in such a way that changes arrive in the database) is the Country column (and changes there should affect all other rows that share the same content; e.g., if you change 'Germany' to 'France' for either VW-car, both should then list 'France' as country).

If you know a way to get the first one editable too, so that the respective columns in the database are updated, that would be really nifty to see, but it's not a requirement. (In my real tables, I use such 'column-joins' for uneditable fields.) 
In this specific case, I would expect a change of 'VW Polo' to 'Marco Polo' to also update 'VW Golf' to 'Marco Golf', as the column used in the column-join is the manufacturers.company and not cars.company. (In reality, one would probably use cars.company for the join though, in which case 'VW Golf' would remain unchanged. But let's assume the query as given above.)

The third column is meant as an example of a calculated stat result, and these are generally only for reading (editing them would not make sense).

**Column Order:**

I would *highly* appreciate being able to choose the order in which the columns are displayed, even across joined tables (like I could do with the Query).

Comment: I'm going to ask you a lot of questions to understand your requirements correctly, to advance the solution will be very particular, I see it almost impossible to generalize it and make it portable. First of all I see that the first column is the union of the first and second column of the Cars table separated by a space, so do you want that when you edit one, change the data in the respective columns?

Comment: The second column is easier to understand, and the third to be a result of an operation that involves a year will only be read, am I right?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have updated my post to answer your questions. Thanks for trying to work this out.

Comment: the optimal solution is using QSqlQueryModel, I will only editable it, is that okay?

Comment: One last question if you change the Country in the VW Gold row, therefore also change the Country in VW Polo, is that what you expect?

Comment: @eyllanesc is you think solving this with QSqlQueryModel is best, that is fine to me, if it's editable. (Actually, I think having an editable QSqlQueryModel subclass might be very helpful to others, as well!) In that case it would be great if you could also explain why, and about the differences in usage between both models (or point to good, easy-to-understand reference (I don't count the Qt documentation as such, as it's hard to understand the details without C++ background).

Comment: Your last update confuses me and I think it's incorrect since it contradicts your previous comments: *the **only column** that really needs to be editable (...) is the **Country column***, so the change it says is not correct, my question was in the sense that if Germany is changed in the consolidated table it should be changed in all rows. and I think that's what you want.

Comment: For example, if the following image https://imgur.com/a/mIj8Z changes Country from the first row from Germany to France, what would be the result?

Comment: @eyllanesc: then the Country in the second row should also change, as the column this refers to is manufactueres.country. Not sure where the confusion comes from? My sentence meant to say that unlike the Country column, editing on the other two columns is optional (or rather: editing on the first column is optional but cool, while editing on the third column is not required as it makes no sense). I have edited, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the great specific solution by @eyllanesc, I have made a generalized version of a QSqlQueryModel where it's possible to specify which columns should be editable. It might need adjustments for other people's queries, but I hope it's helpful to someone out there struggling with similar problems:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

db_file = "test.db"


def create_connection(file_path):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(file_path)
    if not db.open():
        print("Cannot establish a database connection to {}!".format(file_path))
        return False
    return True


def fill_tables():
    q = QSqlQuery()
    q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Manufacturers;")
    q.exec_("CREATE TABLE Manufacturers (Company TEXT, Country TEXT);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Manufacturers VALUES ('VW', 'Germany');")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Manufacturers VALUES ('Honda' , 'Japan');")

    q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;")
    q.exec_("CREATE TABLE Cars (Company TEXT, Model TEXT, Year INT);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('Honda', 'Civic', 2009);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('VW', 'Golf', 2013);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('VW', 'Polo', 1999);")


class SqlQueryModel_editable(QSqlQueryModel):
    """a subclass of QSqlQueryModel where individual columns can be defined as editable
    """
    def __init__(self, editables):
        """editables should be a dict of format: 
        {INT editable_column_nr : (STR update query to be performed when changes are made on this column
                                   INT model's column number for the filter-column (used in the where-clause),
                                   )} 
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.editables = editables

    def flags(self, index):
        fl = QSqlQueryModel.flags(self, index)
        if index.column() in self.editables:
            fl |= Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return fl

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            mycolumn = index.column()
            if mycolumn in self.editables:
                (query, filter_col) = self.editables[mycolumn]
                filter_value = self.index(index.row(), filter_col).data()
                q = QSqlQuery(query.format(value, filter_value))
                result = q.exec_()
                if result:
                    self.query().exec_()
                else:
                    print(self.query().lastError().text())
                return result
        return QSqlQueryModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

    def setFilter(self, myfilter):
        text = (self.query().lastQuery() + " WHERE " + myfilter)
        self.setQuery(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not create_connection(db_file):
        sys.exit(-1)

    fill_tables()

    view = QTableView()

    editables = {1 : ("UPDATE Manufacturers SET Country = '{}' WHERE Company = '{}'", 2)}
    model = SqlQueryModel_editable(editables)
    query = '''
        SELECT (comp.company || " " || cars.model) as Car,
                comp.Country,
                cars.company,
                (CASE WHEN cars.Year > 2000 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) as this_century
        from manufacturers comp left join cars
            on comp.company = cars.company
        '''
    q = QSqlQuery(query)
    model.setQuery(q)
    model.setFilter("cars.Company = 'VW'")
    view.setModel(model)
    view.hideColumn(2)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To make joined columns editable would require more work and a different format for editables, but this should work on any columns that don't hold joined/calculated/aggregated data (like 'Country' in this example).

Comment: Okay, that's what you referred to with generalization, I think it's correct :D

Answer (score 3):

`QSqlTableModel` is a class that inherits from `QSqlQueryModel`, so it can be said that `QSqlTableModel` is a specialized `QSqlQueryModel` to edit a table, so it can be limited or oversized.

For this special case I am proposing a `QSqlQueryModel` Editable, for this I have made the following changes:

- I have enabled the flag `Qt.ItemIsEditable` for the second column.
- I have overwritten the `setData()` method to update the Manufacturers table.
- I have added a column that represents the company, this will be hidden but it is useful to obtain the rows that have to be changed in the previous change.
- I have implemented the `setFilter()` method to make filters.

---

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

db_file = "test.db"


def create_connection(file_path):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(file_path)
    if not db.open():
        print("Cannot establish a database connection to {}!".format(file_path))
        return False
    return True


def fill_tables():
    q = QSqlQuery()
    q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Manufacturers;")
    q.exec_("CREATE TABLE Manufacturers (Company TEXT, Country TEXT);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Manufacturers VALUES ('VW', 'Germany');")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Manufacturers VALUES ('Honda' , 'Japan');")

    q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;")
    q.exec_("CREATE TABLE Cars (Company TEXT, Model TEXT, Year INT);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('Honda', 'Civic', 2009);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('VW', 'Golf', 2013);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('VW', 'Polo', 1999);")


class SqlQueryModel(QSqlQueryModel):
    def flags(self, index):
        fl = QSqlQueryModel.flags(self, index)
        if index.column() == 1:
            fl |= Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return fl

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.column() == 1:
            company = self.index(index.row(), 2).data()
            q = QSqlQuery("UPDATE Manufacturers SET Country = '{}' WHERE Company =  '{}'".format(value, company))
            result = q.exec_()
            if result:
                self.query().exec_()
            else:
                print(self.query().lastError().text())
            return result
        return QSqlQueryModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

    def setFilter(self, filter):
        text = (self.query().lastQuery() + " WHERE " + filter)
        self.setQuery(text)


query = '''
        SELECT (comp.company || " " || cars.model) as Car,
                comp.Country,
                cars.company,
                (CASE WHEN cars.Year > 2000 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) as this_century
        from manufacturers comp left join cars
            on comp.company = cars.company
        '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not create_connection(db_file):
        sys.exit(-1)

    fill_tables()

    view = QTableView()

    model = SqlQueryModel()
    q = QSqlQuery(query)
    model.setQuery(q)
    model.setFilter("cars.Company = 'VW'")
    view.setModel(model)
    view.hideColumn(2)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works nicely! I like the idea of only making the necessary columns specifially editable. I have made a generalized version of this, based on your code, which I'll post as a separate answer because it could be helpful to others with a similar problem. But I could not have done it without your help (or atleast not anytime soon), so you get the bounty. :)

Comment: @CodingCat 
The generalization is very difficult if I do not know all the specific requirements, so I just do it as concrete as possible, then I expected your feedback to fine tune it, but if you have done it seems great. I'm waiting for the bounty :D

Comment: I have to wait 4 more hours before I can award the bounty. :D And yes, as specific as possible is good, as it's often easier to see what's happening.

Comment: How would one implement model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit) in this model? QSqlQueryModel does not seem to have this (unsurprising, as it was not meant to be editable). Can you help, please? (Or should I make this a new question?)

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166429/implementing-seteditstrategy-in-editable-qsqlquerymodel