# How to get filtered rowCount in a QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I use a QSortFilterProxyModel to filter a QSqlTableModel's data, and want to get the filtered rowCount.

But when I call the QSortFilterProxyModel.rowCount method, the QSqlTableModel's rowCount was returned.

So how can I get the filtered rowcount?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734880/layering-proxy-models-in-pyqt

Comment: `proxy.rowCount()` does not return `source_model.rowCount()`, `proxy.rowCount()` returns the number of filtered rows, it seems to me that you are calling `rowCount()` in an inappropriate place so if you need help you should provide a [mcve] but your question will be off-topic: *why isn't this code working?*

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mr.eyllanesc. It seems that I call the rowCount() in an inappropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

You should after set `QSortFilterProxyModel` filter to call `proxymodel.rowCount`。